# Bootstrap 3 navigation styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am unable to add a blue color strip (100%) just behind menu links in 1024 resolution and above? How to add that? Please advise

For now if I add bg color using css it also covers the logo which I don't want. The blue strip should be just below logo for menus. Please help!!!

[Here is the url of my layout](http://idea66.com/mobile/index2.htm)

Thank you
Monica

Comment: I'm getting an "account suspended" at your URL - is it just me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the entire navbar brand code block and paste it above the navbar div:

   ```
   <a href="yourlink.html" class="navbar-brand center-block">
   <img src="http://idea66.com/mobile/images/logo.png" alt="company name"></a>
   ```
2. Remove the class="navbar-brand center-block" from the a href

   ```
   <a href="yourlink.html">
   <img src="http://idea66.com/mobile/images/logo.png" alt="company name"></a>
   ```
3. Add class="center-block" to the img tag that has your logo (don't use navbar-brand)

   ```
   <a href="yourlink.html">
   <img src="http://idea66.com/mobile/images/logo.png" class="center-block" alt="company name"></a>
   ```

It should look like this:

```
    <a href="yourlink.html">
    <img src="http://idea66.com/mobile/images/logo.png" class="center-block" alt="company name"></a>

   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top myNavBar" role="navigation">
```

Then you can style .myNavBar with a blue background

In order to do what are requesting with the logo you will need to have two instances of the logo and use Bootstraps responsive utilities: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Basically you hide the logo above the nav when its down to mobile size by adding hidden-xs in the class:

```
<a href="index.htm">
<img src="images/DECSTARLogo.png" style="width:30%" class="img-responsive center-block hidden-xs" alt="company name"></a>
```

Then add another instance of the logo back into the nav with hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top myNavBar" role="navigation">
<div class="container">

<a href="yourlink.html" class="navbar-brand hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
<img src="http://idea66.com/mobile/images/logo.png" alt="company name"></a>
```

Comment: But if I do that my logo image is not taking img-responsive class. Its not re sizing if I take it out and also in small screens the logo is hidden. Please suggest why?

Comment: Also collapsible menu is not floating to right of logo in lower resolution

http://idea66.com/mobile/index2NavBar.htm